# Insert data into BigQuery table

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Basically my code looks like official example at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

My code:

```
TableRow data = new TableRow();
data.set("type", eventType);
data.set("timestamp", new Date());

TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows row = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
row.setInsertId(System.currentTimeMillis());
row.setJson(data);
request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest();
request.setRows(Arrays.asList(row));

TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(projectId, datasetId, tableId, request).execute();
for (TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrors err: response.getInsertErrors()) {
    for (ErrorProto ep: err.getErrors()) {
        log.error(ep.getReason() + " : " + ep.getMessage() + " at " + ep.getLocation());
    }
}
```

But I getting error:

```
invalid : JSON map specified for non-record field at null
```

Seems that I've missed something, but have no idea what's wrong with my code. I have two fields, a `String` and `Date`, and error message doesn't make any sense to me.

How to insert data in BigQuery table?

Comment: Hello can you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481371/io-exception-while-inserting-data-in-table-on-big-query

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After few hours of debugging I found that BigQuery Java Client doesn't support `Date` values. And `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` wrapper should be used.

So, instead of

```
data.set("timestamp", new Date());
```

there should be:

```
data.set("timestamp", new DateTime(new Date()));
```

Hope it will help somebody.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Probably he will accept, but he must wait 48 hours to do so.

Comment: I got this error: JSON object specified for non-record field: timestamp... What's the type of your "timestamp" field? Mine is DATE, but sould it be DATE_TIME?

Comment: I have an exception if I try to use what you mentioned: `"message":"This field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"`

Comment: @IoTuser I also found that Java API doesn't like DateTime and will throw that exception. The only way I got it to work was to use floating point seconds since UTC. However, my table was expecting a Timestamp NOT a Date so your mileage may vary. My code: tableRow.set("timestamp", millisecondsSinceUtc/1000.0d);