# IO exception while inserting data in table on Big Query

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to insert data in a table on big query.I followed few docs and my final code looks like

```
   HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    List<String> SCOPES = Arrays
            .asList(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY);

    GoogleCredential credential = null;
    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = am.open("hbhjb-8f79f6642470.p12");
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


    File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream, this);


    try {
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("projectnum-*******************3ee3130770087ceab09a482173@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
                .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("BigQuery-Service-Accounts/0.1")
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

    TableRow data = new TableRow();
    data.set("callerNumber", "123456789");


   TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows row = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
    row.setInsertId(System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
    row.setJson(data);
    TableDataInsertAllRequest requests = new TableDataInsertAllRequest();
    requests.setRows(Arrays.asList(row));

    TableDataInsertAllResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll("projectNum", "Data", "CallersData", requests).execute();
        Log.d("big query response", response.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrors err: response.getInsertErrors()) {
        for (ErrorProto ep: err.getErrors()) {
            Log.e("error",ep.getReason() + " : " + ep.getMessage() + " at " + ep.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

now tthe problem is that i am getting IO exception while inserting data i.e on this line

```
 response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll("projectNum", "Data", "CallersData", requests).execute();
```

I am trying to resolve this from last 2 days.If anyone here has implemented it successful please help me to find the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Following is the stacktrace

```
result = {java.io.IOException@830026649024} Method threw 'java.io.IOException'  exception.
 cause = {java.io.IOException@830026649024} "java.io.IOException"
 detailMessage = null
 stackState = null
 stackTrace = {java.lang.StackTraceElement[30]@830026473856} 
 suppressedExceptions = {java.util.Collections$EmptyList@830023143656}  size = 0
```

Comment: what does the exception say?

Comment: @Pentium10 I have added the stack trace..Thanks

Comment: Very odd. Code looks OK to me. I even copied and pasted it into my IDE (of course changed the project id etc.) and it worked just fine i.e the row was successfully streamed to BigQuery. Sorry, I'm stumped.

Comment: @polleyg can this error be caused because of wrong credentials.I mean i have a doubt on the key i have entered here.Can it cause it..??

Comment: @polleyg do we have to do anything spl in manifest or anywhere else.If the same code is working at ur end then there must be a silly mistake.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same code inside a different thread or a Asynctask. Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: I owe you my life.. :D

Comment: As bigquery performing network request, it requires different thread instead main thread for making connection. we can't make network requests on the main thread.